# Creation problem for an array in html with php and xml

Tags: php, html, xml

i have some problem when i want create a simple html array. I use php to get information from a xml file. I get the good information but many times so i want them just one time.

I tried to create 2 for but it is not worth so i delete 1 for and i tried to move the foreach but it is not the real problem, i juste don't know what can i do.

Here is the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<users>
    <info>
        <lname>test</lname>
        <fname>test</fname>
        <email>test@test.com</email>
        <password>******</password>
        <role>Membre</role>
    </info>
    <info>
        <lname>test2</lname>
        <fname>test2</fname>
        <email>test2@test.com</email>
        <password>******</password>
        <role>Super-Administrateur</role>
    </info>
    <info>
        <lname>test3</lname>
        <fname>test3</fname>
        <email>test3@test.com</email>
        <password>*******</password>
        <role>Administrateur</role>
    </info>
</users>
```

Here is the code :

```
<table border="1">
        <?php
        $nbrLigne = $xml->getElementsByTagName('info')->length;
        foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('info') as $item) {
            for ($i=0; $i<$nbrLigne; $i++) {
                echo "<tr>";

                echo "<td>" . $item->parentNode->getElementsByTagName('fname')->item($i)->nodeValue . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $item->parentNode->getElementsByTagName('lname')->item($i)->nodeValue . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $item->parentNode->getElementsByTagName('email')->item($i)->nodeValue . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $item->parentNode->getElementsByTagName('role')->item($i)->nodeValue . "</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </table>
```

Here is the result :

[Result of the test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRBbu.png)

Comment: you probably don't need the `for` loop

Comment: Maybe but if i delete the for what can i do to change the item.
I delete the for, ok i have an array of exactly the number of lines that i want, but all lines have the same content.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, don't know why you're going back up in the tree, using "parentNode". This seems to work :

```
<table border="1">
    <?php
    foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('info') as $item) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $item->getElementsByTagName('lname')->item(0)->nodeValue. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $item->getElementsByTagName('fname')->item(0)->nodeValue. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $item->getElementsByTagName('email')->item(0)->nodeValue. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $item->getElementsByTagName('role')->item(0)->nodeValue. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Also, you could refactor like this, for lisibility:

```
<table border="1">
<?php
foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('info') as $item) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach(['lname', 'fname', 'email', 'role'] as $field){
        echo "<td>" . $item->getElementsByTagName($field)->item(0)->nodeValue. "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: O_o it works !! Thank you !! I don't know too i was using parentNode, maybe its because i use it before and xml is new for me so i try to do the same as before but it doesn't works as we can see ^^

Comment: Pas de souci, je m'arrache tout le temps les cheveux avec, moi aussi ;)